Azure ML - Deploying real time inference pipeline not working with an unknown error
I am trying to deploy a real time inference pipeline for the DenseNet classifier. I'm using Azure's prebuilt pipeline with a different dataset:

I used Azure's "Create inference pipeline" option, which resulted in the following pipeline:

Both pipelines run successfully, but when I try to deploy the inference pipeline, I get the following error:


Realtime endpoint deploy 'aimlops-endpoint' failed
Deploy: Failed on Registering model. Details: Execution encountered an internal error. Contact support for help.

I've running and deploying Azure's prebuilt pipeline "Image Classification with DenseNet" without any modification. Since it's prebuilt, I expected it to run and deploy without issue; however, just like my pipeline the training is successful but deployment meets the same error.

Add the logs details.
